# referencedColumnNames not mapped to a single property error during mapping to a non primary key Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to form a one-to-many relation between two tables with a non primary key id from the parent table but I am getting

> **referencedColumnNames not mapped to a single property.**

Here is the DB table structure with one-to-many relation. The parent table has a compoiste key of(**Email, Emp_SSN**) which is not participating in any relation formation. But the **eid** of parent table **EMP_DETAILS** which has **Unique constraint** and **Not null** is mapped to child table **MODEL_DETAILS** as foreign key.

[image]

Below are the entities create for both child and parent tables.

**EmpDetails.java**

```
@Table(EMP_DETAILS)
@Entity
public class EmpDetails{

 @EmbeddedId
 private EmpDetailsIdentity empIdentity;

 @Id
 @Column(name="eid", nullable=false)
 private Integer eid;

 @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="empDetails"
 private Set<ModelDetails> modelDetailsSet;

 //other column mappings
}
```

**ModelDetails.java**

```
@Table(MODEL_DETAILS)
@Entity
public class ModelDetails{

  @Id
  @Column(name="id)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="eid", nullable=false)
  private EmpDetails empDetails;

  //Other column mappings and getters setters

}
```

**EmpDetailsIdentity.java**

```
@Embeddable
public class EmpDetailsIdentity{
 @Column(name="email") 
 private String email;

 @Column(name="emp_ssn") 
 private String empSsn;

  //getters and setters
}
```

I am not sure what and where am I missing! Can someone please help.

Comment: `@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="eid", nullable=false)` should probably be `@JoinColumn(name="eid", referencedColumnName="eid", optional=false)`

Comment: We do not have optional field for @JoinColumn

Comment: Any help guys? My deadline is nearing and I am finding hard to find any documentation online.

Comment: The `nullable` is for on-the-fly DDL only. You forgot to map `name="eid"` in the `@JoinColumn`. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I tried with the name="eid" as well but id didnt work for me!

Comment: JPA specifies that FK's always need to point to the target's PK (columns). Your reference to a non-PK column won't work. Your `EmpDetails` class defines both `@EmbeddedId` + `@Id`. Use only one. If you want the mappings to work, remove the `@EmbeddedId` class + field and map the two columns separately. Alternatively, keep the `@EmbeddedId` field, remove the `@Id` and use two `@JoinColumn` in the `ModelDetails` class. Which JPA provider are you using?

Comment: It looks like what you want is to remove the `@EmbeddedId` stuff and make `eid` the PK: `@Id @Column(name="eid") private eid;` is sufficient. Map the two fields of the `EmpDetailsIdentity` as simple `@Basic @Column`'s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Kawu, I removed @**EmbeddedId** and deleted **EmpDetailsIdentity**. It does makes sense to remove **embeddedId** as when we are not using **Embeddable** for any relationship mapping. Transferred column mappings from **EmpDetailsIdentity** into **EmpDetails**. The working **EmpDetails** looks like below,

```
@Table(EMP_DETAILS)
@Entity
public class EmpDetails{

 @Id
 @Column(name="eid", nullable=false)
 private Integer eid;

 @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="empDetails"
 private Set<ModelDetails> modelDetailsSet;

 @Column(name="email") 
 private String email;

 @Column(name="emp_ssn") 
 private String empSsn;
}
```

This worked for me! Thanks @Kawu.